# Using custom icons in React Navigation Bottom Tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I use an image as an icon in React Navigation Bottom Tabs? I have my images in a folder inside my project, but to begin with I'm not really sure if I can import images using the `Import {anyComponent} from 'anyPath'`  method. Also, I don't know how to set those custom images as icons. If anyone could give me a hand it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use images like below, basically you can provide your custom component to tabbaricon which can be anything.

```
 <Tab.Screen
          name="Settings1"
          component={SettingsScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'My profile',
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              return (
                <Image
                  style={{ width: size, height: size }}
                  source={{
                    uri:'image url',
                  }}
                />
              );
            },
          }}
        />
```

Comment: This works for setting the image. However the image colour does not update when selected, only the text colour updates. 

Any solution to make the image colour also highlight when selected? I am using a .png image

Comment: @AsadQamber you will have to use different images and switch using the 'focused' parameter